# Как протестировать приложение php на линукс с поддержкой php 7?

Tags: php, linux

Имеется ноут с вин 10. Задача: протестировать код php на линукс. Подскажите как это можно сделать? Смотрел в интернете как вариант развернуть виртуалку прям на винде, либо снести под ноль и поставить линукс, либо арендовать хост или vps на ubunty.
Какой из вариантов наиболее подходящий? Либо предложите свое что-нибудь, я в линуксе полный ноль.

Comment: в зависимости от ноута ещё можно докер поставить или подобную штуку с контейнеризацией.....а так  да, либо виртуалку либо второй системой linux...... арендовать что-то не вариант, т.к. нужно прям тут здесь и сейчас исправлять ошибки, которые возникнут...дебажить и пр..........кстати, а чего на том же VDS не установить винду?)

Comment: Какой лично вам удобнее, тот и подходящий

Comment: на Win 10 можно установить WSL

Comment: @АлексейШиманский винда весит много, а хард это дорогой ресурс на виртуалках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый удобный способ это тестировать с докером `php:7-fpm-alpine`. Но для этого нужно будет изучить докер. Если Вы не девопс, то поставьте Убунту на Виртуалбокс.